# Is it possible to create deprecated version of azure digital twin?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-digital-twins

Currently I am using Azure Digital Twin preview v1 (Microsoft.IoTSpaces/Graph, 2017-10-01-preview) and its deprecated few days back and the microsoft message says it will be retired by the end of 2020.

But I want to create the same deprecated version in another subscription, As i learned there is no way to create the deprecated version of Digital Twin via portal.

Will azure support me to create the deprecated version via ARM template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a confirmation from Microsoft's Product Team and below is the quote.

> *We are not allowing any new instances of ADTv1 to be created. As the service is being sunset, we want to move everyone to the new version
> (v2) !*

Comment: THanks for your answer. You are right, using portal its not possible to create the older version. But using ARM template we can create it.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated version(Microsoft.IoTSpaces/Graph, 2017-10-01-preview) going to expire in the end of 2020.

Until then if it really required, we can create the older version by using ARM Template.

I have created it using ARM template already.